# Capital letter for the word following Inc

Tags: grammar, abbreviations

In the context of a catalogue, if a product comes with a charging cable for example, should it be typed:

- Inc. Charging cable. or
- Inc. charging cable.

Comment: What is the full entry in the catalog where this occurs?

Comment: The period after "Inc" is not a "full stop" to end a sentence, but rather a punctuation that indicates an abbreviation.  "Inc." would be treated exactly like "Including" in virtually all cases where that abbreviation is being used.  (Note that it gets a bit more complex when "Incorporated" is being abbreviated, but still the word after would not generally be affected.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lower case.

You wouldn't write:

"included Milk, Wheat, Water, ..."

wouldn't you?

Comment: Well, you might capitalize "Milk" if you're of the conviction that the word after `:` should be capitalized.

Comment: Lower case is as I thought and from the same reasoning. Thank you for settling a debate with a colleague!